# How to define CellPadding in GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

- I autoformat a GridView in ASP.NET.
- It looks nice but the headers all run together like this:

  **idfirstNamelastNameage**
- I set CellPadding="5" but it does nothing.

How can I set the cell padding of the headers and all cells?

A D D E N D U M :

Thanks Andrew, I fixed it with this. Works in Firefox and Explorer 7:

```
.gridview2 tr td
{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.gridview2 tr th
{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should set a cssclass and use css to control it. The only property of a table you cant fully control cross browser with css is cellspacing.

```
.myTableClass tr th {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Update: Bear in mind this is 5 years old, only ancient versions of IE suffer from the cellspacing css issue

Answer (score 4):

GridView also has a property "CellPadding" and "CellSpacing" that can help us do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated HTML and find the table it has created. Check the ID of the table. With the id, add following lines to your CSS. This worked for me when all else failed..

```
#YourTableIdFoo th , #YourTableIdFoo td 
{
    padding-right:      1em;
}
```

Comment: The generated html table has no id attribute, even when the GridView in the markup has one.