# Cell Padding not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using *GridView* to export a table to Excel.

I have this in my controller:

```
GridView gv = new GridView();

gv.DataSource = lstExportedExcel.ToList(); // lstExportedExcel does have stuff in it
gv.DataBind();

gv.HeaderRow.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[5].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[8].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[9].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[10].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[11].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[12].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;

gv.CellPadding = 10; //doesn't work

Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DailySummaryExport.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

I have done research on this, and a lot of the solutions are on the *front-end*, but how do I get this to work?  When I open the excel spreadsheet, the text in each cell isn't getting the padding from the default border.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to be more explicit, try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316931/how-to-define-cellpadding-in-gridview-in-asp-net

Comment: @IrishChieftain I don't have a specific view for this *gridview*, this gridview is being created on the fly, so how would I would get *CSS* to work?  There is a *CssClassName* property for GridView.. but I am lost on how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Working blind here, but give this a shot:

Add to your style sheet:

```
.gv tr th
{
    padding: 10px;
}

.gv tr td
{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Then set the class dynamically in your code:

```
gv.CssClass = "gv";
```

Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.cellpadding(v=vs.110).aspx):

"All cells in the same column of a GridView control have the same width. The padding amount is applied to the widest cell and all other cells in the column have this cell width. Similarly, all cells in the same row have the same height. The padding amount is applied to the tallest cell in the row and all other cells in the row have this cell height. Individual cell sizes cannot be specified."

Comment: sorry but no luck.. i really don't understand why they have a *CellPadding* property when it doesn't work efficiently..

Comment: Take a look a this, the approach should work if you play around with it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607547/define-global-site-style-for-aspgridview-with-plain-css-without-using-vs-skins